# what's the essential difference between int a=0; and int a; a=0;?

Tags: java

```
int a=0;

int a; a=0;
```

what's the essential difference between them?

I have this code:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    int a=0;

    int b;
    //   ^
    b=0;
```

My IDE shows a red squiggly where I have the `^` above:

[image: picture of the code above]

In Java anonymous inner class, why is it showing the red squiggly for the second statement  but not the first?

Comment: It is largely a style choice and the statement can be used in anonymous inner classes.  The reason Java supports this is because in `C` the later used to be your only choice and the former came later.

Comment: Both are correct in C and Java

Comment: I suspect that both will compile to the same bytecode.

Comment: If `a` is part of a method that contains a class and you want to use `a` inside the contained class, then you will have to do `final int a=0;` which is slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why your IDE is showing the red squiggly where it is, but the problem is with the

```
b=0;
```

line. At that point, you're in the top level of your class. You can't have assignments there, they can only be in methods, constructors, or initializer blocks. The reason `int a=0;` works is that it's an initializer on a member declaration, which *is* allowed.

A simpler example might make this clearer:

```
class Example {

    int a = 0; // This is fine, it's an initializer on a member declaration

    int b;     // This is also fine, it's a member declaration

    b = 0;     // This is an error, it's an assignment that isn't in a method,
               // constructor, or initializer block

    {
        b = 0; // This is fine, because it's inside an *instance* initializer
               // block. These blocks are run when an instance is being
               // constructed, just before the constructor is called
    }

    static int c;

    static {
        c = 0; // This is fine, because it's inside a *static* initializer block
               // These blocks are run when the class (as a whole, not an 
               // instance) is being initialized
    }

    void method() {
        b = 0; // This is fine, because it's inside a method
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!I'm a chinese student with poor English,and a newcomer to stackoverflow.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

In the picture uploaded by you, there is not a coding block, there is class space not inside a method

Also you can use second statemant see:

```
public class myclass{

    int a;
    {
        a = 0;
    }

}
```

Note: such a blocks are called **initializer blocks**